Existence of FHE scheme that supports evaluation of obfuscated Quantum Functionalities
While reading this paper I came across the following text:

A natural approach to obfuscation involves the notion of fully-
homomorphic encryption (FHE), which allows for encoding data x into a ciphertext Enc(x) so that
anyone holding Enc(x) and a function f can produce a ciphertext Enc(f(x)). Indeed, given an
FHE scheme that supports the evaluation of quantum functionalities [Mah18], one could release
an encryption Enc(Q) of the description of Q. Then, any evaluator with an input x can obtain
Enc(Q(x)) by running an appropriate evaluation procedure.

The definition of a QHFE scheme is as follows:
$
Gen(1^\lambda,D) \rightarrow (sk,pk) :\space \text{where D is the circuit depth, $\lambda$ is the security parameter and sk,pk are the key pairs}
\\
Enc(pk,x) \rightarrow ct: \text{Encryption algorithm which generates classical ct from public key pk and classical x}
\\
Eval(Q,ct) \rightarrow \tilde{ct}: \text{On input quantum circuit Q and ct, the quantum evaluation algorithm gives evaluated ciphertext $\tilde{ct}$} 
\\
Dec(sk,ct) \rightarrow x: \text{On input a secret key sk and classical ct, decryption algorithm returns message x}
$
As I understand it, this paragraph suggests that we take a QFHE scheme of the following form:
$
Gen(1^\lambda,D) \rightarrow (sk,pk) \\
Enc(pk,q) \rightarrow \tilde{q} : \text{Where q is the classical description of the quantum circuit Q that is to be obfuscated and $\tilde q$ is the obfuscated circuit}
\\
Eval(U,\tilde{q},x) \rightarrow ct: \text{U is a universal quantum circuit that takes as input a classical description q of a quantum circuit Q, and an input x and gives the output $U(q,x) = Q(x)$}
\\
Dec(sk,ct) \rightarrow Q(x): \text{The decryption algorithm outputs the unobfuscated output of the original quantum circuit Q}
$
However, I can't find the mention of the existence of any such FHE scheme in Mahadev's paper.
Questions:
Is my interpretation of this obfuscation correct?

Can you give me some reference of the existence of any such scheme?

The interpretation looks correct.
A lot of the details for Mahadev's scheme are trivial and skipped over quite quickly and the difficult parts are mainly covered in the paper.
The universal $U$ is chosen and decomposed into a circuit of only Clifford and $CCX$ gates.
The quantum state is encrypted with a one time pad $X^xZ^z |\psi\rangle$ and a classical FHE encryption of (x,z) is given.
The circuit is implemented on the state. Whenever a Clifford ,$C$, gate is applied, the state transforms as $CX^xZ^zC^\dagger C|\psi\rangle$ and we have $CX^xZ^zC^\dagger = X^{x'}Z^{z'}$. The classical FHE updates the encryption of the keys and we progress.
The main issue arises when $C = CCX$. Here we the padding wont transform into a new encryption key but produce additional $CX,CZ$ gates. Telling the server to undo these unwanted gates are equivalent to telling the server the encryption keys, which is bad.
The main focus of the work is a quantum algorithm that allows the server to us e $Enc(d)$ to implement $X^xZ^z CX^d$. Since the Server has the encryption of the keys, they can undo these extra errors occured and the computation can continue.
Decryption is simply measuring the state and the Client uses the one time pad to work out the true measurements.
